# How to make individual points at JChart2D?

Tags: java, java-2d, graphic

I am using JChart2D for my Java desktop application and followed that example:

http://jchart2d.sourceforge.net/usage.shtml

That example makes connections between points however I need individual points.

I mean I get something like:

[image]

But I want something like:

[image]

**PS:** Graphic examples are different just I wanted to show difference between individual points and line between points.

Answer (score 3):

Close, but no cigar. The correct API Call is:

```
Chart2D chart = new Chart2D();
ITrace2D trace = new Trace2DSimple();
// Add the trace to the chart:
chart.addTrace(trace);
trace.setTracePainter(new TracePainterDisc(4));
```

The call

```
trace.setTracePainter(new TracePainterDisc(4));
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer lies in the link you posted above.

Create a trace (instance of [ITrace2D](http://jchart2d.sourceforge.net/docs/javadoc/info/monitorenter/gui/chart/ITrace2D.html#setPointHighlighter%28info.monitorenter.gui.chart.IPointPainter%29)) and set the [PointPainter](http://jchart2d.sourceforge.net/docs/javadoc/index.html) e.g. to [PointPainterDisc](http://jchart2d.sourceforge.net/docs/javadoc/index.html).

Derived from the API javadoc:

```
Chart2D test = new Chart2D();
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chart2D- Debug");

frame.setSize(400,200);
frame.setVisible(true);
ITrace2D atrace = new Trace2DLtd(100);

atrace.setPointHighlighter(new PointPainterDisc(5));
test.addTrace(atrace);
while(expression){
  atrace.addPoint(adouble,bdouble);
  ....
}
```

Comment: This PointPainterDisc is for making a disc where mouse points.

Answer (score 0):

```
trace.setTracePainter(new TracePainterDisc());
```